# Chi-square test for 3 dimensions: Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel Test post-hoc interpretation

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared

From a food microbiological data, I have the following variables (showing only the head):

```
 TYPE  YEAR     Escherichiacoli
1 Spreadable 2018 Not detected
2 Sliced 2018 Not detected
3 Spreadable 2018 Not detected
4 Pork 2018 Not detected
5 Pork 2018     Detected
6 Spreadable 2018 Not detected
```

n = 600

All variables are categorical. However, I have 3 dimensions. I want to study if exists statistical differences between detection and not detection for each type of food and year.

Then, I thought that the Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel Test. I don't have experience in this kind of test.

However the example tutorial for the Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel Test, and in detail for their post-hoc analysis (https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_06.html) I don't know if I interpret it correctly.

I attach below the output for the post-hoc analysis for the example detailed in the previous webpage if someone can agree with me or no that I interpret properly each dimension. Thanks on advance.

**Third-dimension:**

```
> groupwiseCMH(Table,
+              group   = 3, # Group 3 refers to country (see example in webpage)
+              fisher  = TRUE,
+              gtest   = FALSE,
+              chisq   = FALSE,
+              method  = "fdr",
+              correct = "none",
+              digits  = 3)

        Group   Test p.value  adj.p
1       Bloom Fisher  0.0468 0.0936
2 Cobblestone Fisher  0.0102 0.0408
3      Dougal Fisher  0.5230 0.5230
4    Heimlich Fisher  0.1750 0.2330
```

Then, I can say that in Cobblestone there are statistical significant difference between pass or not the exam.

**Second-dimension:**

```
> groupwiseCMH(Table,
+              group   = 2,# Variable exam --> two levels: Pass/Fail
+              fisher  = TRUE,
+              gtest   = FALSE,
+              chisq   = FALSE,
+              method  = "fdr",
+              correct = "none",
+              digits  = 3)

  Group   Test p.value adj.p
1  Pass Fisher   0.285 0.285
2  Fail Fisher   0.241 0.285
```

From this output, I understand that at global terms there are no statistical differences between pass or fail the exam.

**First-dimension:**

```
> groupwiseCMH(Table,
+              group   = 1, # Variable of Sex.
+              fisher  = TRUE,
+              gtest   = FALSE,
+              chisq   = FALSE,
+              method  = "fdr",
+              correct = "none",
+              digits  = 3)

   Group   Test p.value  adj.p
1 Female Fisher  0.8240 0.8240
2   Male Fisher  0.0121 0.0242
```

For this output, I can say that in males, but not for females there are statistical differences in passing the exam.

I really appreciate your feedback if I interpret correctly the post-hoc tests for  Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel Test. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a statistical question rather than a programming question. I have voted to migrate it to Cross Validated, our sister stack exchange site for statistical questions.

Comment: Thank you Allan Cameron for your observation. I didn't know. I  have migrated this question to CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569645/chi-square-test-for-3-dimensions-cochran-mantel-haenszel-test-post-hoc-interpre  Thank you